# Two figures with side captions next to one another

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, positioning, captions

I currently have the following figure placed at the bottom of my page:

```
\begin{SCfigure}[][h]
    \centering
    \caption{Georg Cantor (1845--1918)}
    \includegraphics[height=\measurepage]{images/Georg_Cantor2}
    \label{fig:cantor}
\end{SCfigure}
```

However, I would like to place another figure with side captions right next to it. I can't use the normal `figure` environment because I really need those side captions. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the `floatrow` package instead: it has option for caption placement, incl. sideways caption in the ordinary figure environment, and cooperates with the  `caption` package.

Comment: @Bernard Could you please elaborate? I'd appreciate it if you could write up a full answer using that.

Comment: OK I'll try to do that in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a  small illustration of how to use the `floatrow` package. On first page, a row of illlustrations, with the `\floatrow` environment, inside a `figure` environment. To have stacked figures, it is enough  to use the `\fcapside{\caption{…}\label{…}}` command. The side caption can be placed top, center, or bottom, left, right, inside, or outside, through a system of keywords.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[textwidth =15cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx, floatrow}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{QQuad}%
{\begingroup\hskip 4em\endgroup}
 \floatsetup{capbesideposition={bottom,outside},capbesidesep =QQuad}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{AliceSteadman.png}}{\caption{Ralph Steadman’s \emph{Alice}}\label{stead}}

\ffigbox{\includegraphics{sendak.png}}{\caption{\emph{Where the Wild Things are}}\label{send}}
 \end{floatrow}
 \end{figure}
 \clearpage

  \begin{figure}
 \fcapside{\caption{Ralph Steadman’s \emph{Alice}}\label{stead}}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{AliceSteadman.png}}
\end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
\fcapside{\caption{\emph{Where the Wild Things are}}\label{send1}}{\includegraphics{sendak.png}}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick adaption of a piece of code (based on KOMA-Script) might help you to develop your solution.:

```
\documentclass[paper =a4, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove option demo if you have the graphic

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
{
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \begin{captionbeside}{First Box}%
    {\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=18.5mm]{graphic}}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
  \ % Some space in between
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
%
  \begin{captionbeside}{SecondBox}%
    {\includegraphics[width=30mm,height=18.5mm]{graphic}}
  \end{captionbeside}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{figure}\par

\end{document}
```

I hope it is close to your requirements.